# Juno re-positions detached windows on perspective change

Tags: view, positioning, perspective, detach

I recently upgraded to Juno to take advantage of the java 1.7 features, and now my views don't behave properly.

I work on multiple monitors and have the views (Package Explorer, Outline, etc) detached and placed on a separate monitor so that I can have a full screen view of the current editor and the view.

However, when I switch between perspectives ( java and debug ), the detached views get repositioned right on top of the editors and I have to move them to get to the editor.

I tried saving both the perspectives after I got everything positioned correctly, but that doesn't help, whether or not I restart.

Is there a trick to making the detached windows position permanent like was in Indigo?